# Change bin size in Excel surface plot

Tags: microsoft-excel

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find a solution online.  I'm creating surface plots in Excel, and I wanted to see if there was a way to set the bin size for coloring.  Right now Excel defaulted to 4 bins (colors) for my data, but I want to display more to have more of a gradient effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to do it (if I understand your question correctly) in Excel 2007 by clicking on the vertical axis, doing right-click → `Format Axis…`, and then setting the “Major unit” to a Fixed value smaller than the default (“Auto”) value.

[image: the chart that I created]
                [image: the "Format Axis" dialog box]

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  Is there a way to do this with a 2D contour plot?  It's defaulting to a certain number of contour curves, but I would like to see more.

Comment: Umm…  What happens when you try ***the exact same answer***?

Comment: On a 2D contour plot, there is no vertical axis to click on.

Comment: @Amy: OK, perhaps I misunderstood the question.  What, exactly, do you mean by “a 2D contour plot”?  I don’t see any such chart option in Excel 2007.            //            P.S. When you ask questions like these, it’s a good idea to specify _which version_ of the software you are using, because features and capabilities change, and therefore so do answers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Excel 2010.  In the available chart types, under Surface there is a type called contour.  I actually just found the answer here: http://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/782238-changing-the-resolution-of-a-contour-plot-in-excel-2010-a.html

Comment: For contours it works the same way. In Chart Tools > Layout > Axis, you can select the vertical axis as well.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem.  To clarify:
If you're using a 2D surface plot (ie, a contour plot "viewed" from directly overhead), you can't edit the colour ranges.  You need to switch to a 3D surface plot (which has all three axes), and edit the vertical axis in that.  Then when you switch back to a 2D surface plot, those edited values will be applied.

Answer (score 2):

I was working with a contour graph (2D view from overhead of a 3D surface plot) and found that if I selected Vertical (Value) Axis from the drop down on either the Layout or Format tabs (under Chart Tools), I could adjust the ranges just fine. No need to swap to a 3D view and back.